# To print the value of array.under array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, recursion

I have to print the all the value of the array written value.

```
[subscriber] => Array
    (
        [name] => Subscriber
        [capabilities] => Array
            (
                [read] => 1
                [level_0] => 1
            )
        [default] => Array
            (
                [deft] => Array (
                              [one] => 2
                              [two] => 3
                        )
                [deft_one] => Array (
                               [one] => t
                               [two] => h
                        )
            )

    )
```

I have to print each value under the array. So i used a recursion function. But i cant the result. Please help me in recursion function.

Sorry, I am trying till now. Actually i have to print the wp-option table value. There are many serialise array. I want to print all the value individually. I mean when i used the code written bellow i got an array.

```
function option_value_change () {
  global $wpdb;
  $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
  FROM `wp_options`");
    $temp_url = get_option('siteurl');
    $site_url = get_site_url();
    foreach ($myrows as $rows){
      $option = get_option($rows->option_name);
                //print_r($option);
        get_option_value($option);
    }
}
```

i can get the table. But in an array. Which array have arrays. So i used an function  "get_option_value($option)". as written bellow

```
function get_option_value($option) {
    if(!is_object($option) && !is_array($option)){
        echo $option;
    }
    else{
            foreach($option as $option_value){
                if(!is_array($option_value)){
                    echo $option_value;
                }
                else {
                    get_option_value($option_value);

                }
            }
    }
}
```

bUt i cant get all the value. its give an error as

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.
```

So how can i print all the values of the array.

Comment: Can we see your recursive function?

Comment: Put your function. Tell where it went wrong. Show what exactly you want.

Comment: Can you get my problem now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RecursiveArrayIterator` example :

```
$data = array(
  'subscriber' => array(
    'name' => 'Subscriber',
    'capabilities' => array(
      'read' => 1,
      'level_0' => 1,
    ),
    'default' => array(
      'deft' => array(
        'one' => 2,
        'two' => 3,
      ),
      'deft_one' => array(
        'one' => 't',
        'two' => 'h',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

echo "<pre>";
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
foreach($it as $var)
{
    echo $var , PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Output

```
Subscriber
1
1
2
3
t
h
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when i used your code, it give an error like Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead

Comment: Can see my edited question ? I used now your code "echo "<pre>";
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($option));
foreach($it as $var)
{
    echo $var , PHP_EOL ;
}

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but you can get the idea;

```
function printArr($obj){

    if(!is_array($obj)){

        echo $obj;
        return;
    }
    else if(is_array($obj)){

        foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
            printArr($obj[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```